# Laravel Blade Loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using `ceil()` method to count how many  `<div class="item">` block it should create. Each `.item` can only have 4 `img`.

I am having problem figuring out how to allow 4 `img` only and then create next `.item` block via loop.

```
    @foreach(range(1, ceil($product->photos->count()/4)) as $section)
    <div class="item">
        <div class="row">
            @foreach($product->photos as $photo)
                <img src="{{$photo->photo_url}}" alt="" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="{{$loop->index}}" class="galleryItem">
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use chunk method in foreach like

```html
  @foreach($posts->chunk(2) as $tempPosts)
  <div class = "row">
   @foreach($tempPosts as $post)
   /* your  code*/
   @endforeach
  </div>
  @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`chunk()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-chunk):

```
@foreach($product->photos->chunk(4) as $photos)
    <div class="item">
        <div class="row">
            @foreach($photos as $photo)
                <img src="{{$photo->photo_url}}" alt="" data-target="#carousel" class="galleryItem">
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: $product is collection, not array.

Comment: Ohh, use `chunk()` then. Updated the answer.